# Filtering EF query based on filter object automatically

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, reflection, expression-trees

Let's say we have the following classes:

```
class A
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
} 

class FilterA
{
    public List<int> Ids {get; set;}
    public List<string> Names {get; set;}
}
```

I have an IQueryable which I need to filter based on values provided in FilterA in some generic way, because in real project I have to deal with there are hundreds of such objects each having tens of properties and I'm sick and tired of writing spaghetti code like this:

```
if(filter.Ids.Any())
{
    query = query.Where(q=>filter.Ids.Contains(q.Id));
}

if(filter.Names.Any())
{
    query = query.Where(q=>filter.Names.Contains(q.Name));
}  
...
```

I tried to implement this by myself couple times, but failed. The main problem from my perspective is that I can't specify the list of expressions returning different types, so ended up with some horrible, huge and unreadable reflection each time. So maybe I'm missing some obvious way of doing that or there are existing solutions for this already - anything will work unless it's not a mile of unreadable code, just don't want the cure to be worse than the disease.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is to introduce extension method so checks can be turned into one liners/chained (actual method name is up to you):

```cs
public static class QueryableExts
{
    private static MethodInfo? _methodInfo = typeof(Enumerable)
        .GetMethod(nameof(Enumerable.Contains), 
            new []
            {
                typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(Type.MakeGenericMethodParameter(0)),
                Type.MakeGenericMethodParameter(0)
            });

    public static IQueryable<T> WhereInNotNullOrEmpty<T, TKey>(this IQueryable<T> q, Expression<Func<T, TKey>> selector, IEnumerable<TKey>? values)
    {
        if (values == null || !values.Any())
        {
            return q;
        }
        var collection = Expression.Constant(values);
        var contains = Expression.Call(_methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TKey)), collection, selector.Body);
        var expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(contains, selector.Parameters);
        expression.Compile();
        return q.Where(expression);
    }
}
```

And usage:

```
query = query
    .WhereInNotNullOrEmpty(q => q.Id, filter.Ids)
    .WhereInNotNullOrEmpty(q => q.Name, filter.Names);
```

Other then that you are limited to using some code generation/reflection if you want to apply this filtering in more dynamic way. I would argue that using [source generators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview) can be more preferable approach then reflection for this in modern .NET.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense. Would be cool to do it like List<?>{(q => q.Id, filter.Ids), (q => q.Name, filter.Names)}.ForEach(WhereInNotNullOrEmpty)

Comment: @KorsaR maybe you can look into something like creating your own collection but personally I would leave this as is.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll rework this later with generic attributes once they'll get introduced. Will stick with your solution meanwhile, it looks much better than it is now

Comment: @KorsaR how are you planning to use the generic attributes here? Note that you can call this `WhereInNotNullOrEmpty` with reflection generically also, it is not hard to build the property access expression manually.

Comment: I was thinking about having some mapping attribute in filter object which will accept Expression Func to map filter property to the property which needs to be filtered. Then I'll just loop over properties having this attribute calling your method for each of them. At the moment  I can just pass string property name of course, but this will produce really ugly parsing reflection as I can see

Comment: @KorsaR AFAIK generic attributes should not allow anything like passing expression trees.

Comment: you're right, I misunderstood the concept. Well, then there is  not much I can improve apparently :)